# Add a viewcontroller in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a storyboard and have too a UITableViewController class which isn't in storyboard.xib.

I have 2 viewcontrollers in storybaord.xib and I can pushViewController my UITableViewController from one ...but not from other..

```
 ViewControllerB *viewController=[[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
viewController.string=@"tunvir";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

the code is the same in both others viewControllers...but this code works in one and not in other

More infos: 
I'm using auto layout...before I use auto layout it works in both.

The full code for UITableViewController.h
http://pastebin.com/WdqQPVwN

and .m

http://pastebin.com/ptyeLmpL

Comment: Can you please add the code from both viewControllers -- the one that is working and the one that's not working?

Comment: the one that is working is a normal UIViewController...the code is too big..and the one thats not working is one UIVIewController. The difference beetween their is that the one which works is on storyboard.xib and the one that doesn't work not

Comment: No! :) But glad you got this resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned your tableView is not in storyboard but has a  separate .xib file. This should work.

```
YourTableViewCtonroller *vc = [[YourTableViewCtonroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewXibName" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourTableViewCtonroller animated:YES];
```

Comment: my tableviewcontroller hasn't xib file my code is ` FilterListViewController* flvc = [[FilterListViewController alloc] initWithSelectedCategories:self.location.categories deleagte:self];` `[self.navigationController presentViewController:flvc animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: I've created a UITableViewController in sotoryboard.xib and create a segue. I will mark as correct answer because you gave me the ideia to create a xib..thanks